# How angular Component get return object from service after http post?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using `angular 4`. How can I get return object from service?

```
export class LoginRequest {
  username : string;
  password : string;
}

export class LoginResponse {
  token : string;
  message : string;
  status : string;
}
```

LoginComponent.ts

```
export class LoginComponent {
    ...
    loginRes : LoginResponse;
    ...

    login(loginReq : LoginRequest)  {
        // here how can I get return object
        this.loginRes = this.loginService.login(this.loginReq);
    }
}
```

LoginService.ts

```
export class LoginService {
    ...
    loginRes : LoginResponse;
    ...

    login()  {
        // here how can I return  loginRes object
        this.http.post(API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq)
        .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.loginRes =  res.json() as LoginResponse;
            },  
            err => {
                this.loginRes = new LoginResponse();
                this.loginRes.message = "Failed to conntect the server";
                this.loginRes.status = "NOT_OK";
                this.loginRes;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginRes : LoginResponse;
  login()  {
    this.loginService.login(this.loginReq).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loginRes =  res.json() as LoginResponse;
      }, 
      err =>{
        this.loginRes = new LoginResponse();
        this.loginRes.message = "Failed to conntect the server";
        this.loginRes.status = "NOT_OK";
      }
    );
    console.log(this.loginRes.message + " Response Data");
  }
}   

export class LoginService {

  login(loginReq : LoginRequest) {
    return this.http.post(Constant.API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq);
  }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should return your http. `return this.http.post....`

Comment: @ochs.tobi If I do like that, caller method did not get my required object 'loginRes'.

Comment: Subscribe in the component not in the service. Then it will work

Comment: Also, you ddont need `.json()` in Angular 4 `httpClient` anymore

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Change your service to:

```
export class LoginService {
...
loginRes : LoginResponse;
...
 // returning with type here
 login(): Observable<LoginResponse>  {
    return this.http.post(API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq)
 }
}
```

and then in component:

```
export class LoginComponent {
  ...
  loginRes : LoginResponse;
  ...

  login(loginReq : LoginRequest)  {
    // here how can I get return object
    this.loginService.login(this.loginReq)
       .subscribe( res => {
          // handle "success"/"error" accordingly,
          this.loginRes = res;
       })
  }
}
```

**Also, Make sure you are `unsubscribing` the during `ngDestroy()` phase if you are not using `async` pipe directly**

#### update 1

1. Don't just declare `loginRes : LoginResponse;`, define `loginRes : LoginResponse = new LoginResponse();`.  Reason being, its an observable, it's async. So, trying to `print` without making sure that its been initialized will cause `undefined` error
2. use `console.log(this.loginRes.message + " Response Data");` inside `finally()` as a good practice

Comment: there are  compile in 
login(): Observable<LoginResponse>  {
    return this.http.post(API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq)
 }

Comment: @CycDemo : and whats the error ? I think it will surely not be a major one. Share the error / screenshot and I'll see

Comment: @CycDemo : How have you declared `this.loginRes` in component. Also, is `console.log(this.loginRes.message + " Response Data");` on line 34 ?

Answer (score 0):

Send `http` response from `server` and `subscribe` in `component`

So, in service, just `return api call`

```
return this.http.post(API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq)
```

**Component:**

```
export class LoginComponent {
    loginRes : LoginResponse;

    login(loginReq : LoginRequest)  {
        // here how can I get return object
        this.loginService.login(this.loginReq).subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.loginRes =  res;
            },  
            err => {
                console.log(err, 'errrrr')
                this.loginRes = new LoginResponse();
                this.loginRes.message = "Failed to conntect the server";
                this.loginRes.status = "NOT_OK";
                this.loginRes;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
export class LoginService {
    loginRes : LoginResponse;

    login()  {
        return this.http.post(API_URL + "weblogin", loginReq)

    }
}
```

Comment: I already try this one
I get error in console.log(this.loginRes.message + " Response Data");
like 'Cannot read property 'message' of undefined'

Comment: `this.loginRes =  res;`

Comment: I added one `console.log` please check in the answer

Comment: remove  `console.log(this.loginRes.message + " Response Data");`

Comment: and send the `console.log` which you get, I also added `console` in error, if any case it goes to error

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using '@angular/http':**

login-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class LoginService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    login(credentials) {
        return this.http.post(`API_URL`, credentials)
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**If you are using '@angular/common/http':**

login-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class LoginService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    login(credentials) {
        return this.http.post(`API_URL`, credentials)
        .map(res => res);
    }
}
```

**The component:**

login-component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login-service.ts';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class LoginComponent {

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

    login(loginReq : LoginRequest) {
        this.loginService.login(loginReq)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    }
}
```